# Windows Phone 8 Development Testing on Device Error

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

> Error  1   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
>   SmartDeviceException - The target device is running an unsupported version of the operating system.
>
> Error  2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. The target device is running an unsupported version of the operating system.

When testing on my Lumia 920 device, which is up to date in its OS, these are the 2 errors that occur when trying to test my app on Visual Studio 2013.

I have both a registered developer account and device. The emulator works perfectly fine, but device testing does not work. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: If you are use visual studio 2013 it will targets to windows phone 8.1. Which OS are using in your Phone...? If OS is windows phone 8 it won't support.

Comment: I am facing same issue for model Nokia Lumia 1520 OS version 8.1.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar have you tried doing a BIOS update?

Comment: Also make sure the Date and Time are set correctly on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

For some , the issue was resolved by launching VS 2013 as Administrator. Give it a try and see if it resolves.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a data cable issue. Hope you're using the compatible Data Cable for your device. If not, try using compatible data cable that will solve your problem.